# Code highlighting in Peek Definition window of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem about code highlighting in Peek Definition window of Visual Studio Code.

When I peek any function or class code with Peek Definition, the entire code block, not only the function or class name, will be highlighted with bright orange background, so that it's hard to read the code for me.

I attached a sample image of the situation.

I'll appreciate your help.

[image: An example of the highlighted code]

Comment: You can probably find the needed color in here: [workbench colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_peek-view-colors)

Answer (score 13):

Since no one officially answered your question, I figured I'll just post the solution (thanks @Alex for the hint!):

1. Open the settings menu

   - On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
   - On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings
2. Search for `Color Customizations` and click on `Edit in settings.json`
3. Insert your custom highlighting (`peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground`) in the right window:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[*Your Theme*]": {
        "peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground": "*Your Chosen Color*"
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

If you'd like to make other changes to the peek editor, take a look at the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_peek-view-colors).